# Is their any way I can **not** round off the number while using parseInt?

Tags: javascript, parseint

```
let display = '5+10.10';
let numbers = display.match(/(\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)/g).map(a => parseInt(a));
console.log(numbers)//returns [5, 10]
```

when I don't use `parseInt`:

```
let display = '5+10.10';
let numbers = display.match(/(\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)/g);
console.log(numbers)//returns ["5", "10.10"]
```

I need the array item's as an number with decimal  rather than a string.

Comment: Do you know what an interger / int is? It is a whole number, no matter what. If you want floating point numbers use `parseFloat` instead.

Comment: `let numbers = display.match(/(\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)/g).map(Number);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parseInt` converts to Integer. You want `parseFloat` :

```js
let display = '5+10.10';
let numbers = display.match(/(\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)/g).map(a => parseFloat(a));
console.log(numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let numbers = display.match(/(\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)/g).map(Number);
```

you can use the broader Number here, because an integer by definition will never have a decimal part.